# How i can use Koala on FTP connection?

Tags: koala

I'm using Less for front-end designs. I use Koala for convert less to css codes. I want use it when i work with ftp(online). Is it possible? Ie, how export to ftp with Koala?

Comment: Try to upload (ftp) your compiled files on change, for instance leveraging Grunt, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878866/grunt-watch-a-file-and-sftp-when-its-changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try Prepros app for compiling any less files for your awesome project Fatih.

Here is the offical link. https://prepros.io/

This is better than Koala.

Comment: This is nice alternative for me. Thanks namesake. What is Prepros full version goods? Do you have information on this?

Comment: yeah. actually nothing. here is the more info about this. http://discuss.prepros.io/t/what-is-the-difference-between-paid-and-trial-free-version/31

Comment: Very simple and great, can compile and can upload resulting css to FTP (right click on folder to setup Project Settings) on file change. You can choose which files upload.

Comment: only not as free as Koala is, as it quite often flashes requests to go pro from the second day of use